# Article from Springer template package is not centered

Tags: margins

I downloaded:

https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

And this is how it compiles:

[image]

Pages have different margins. Is it how it supposed to be? If I'm writing my paper based on that it is broken in the same way. I have \documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl} there.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The alignment is appropriate for two-sided pages, where the "inside" margin is on the binding edge, and the wider margin is "outside", and allows for annotations or dirty thumbprints.

Comment: So fortunately everything is fine. I wouldn't have figured it out on my own. I was already trying hard to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting `twoside,` from line 122 of `sn-jnl.cls` causes the alignment to default to `oneside` behaviour. The margin misalignment can be reintroduced by passing `twoside` as an argument to `\documentclass{sn-jnl}`.

Notably this behaviour is intended as the inside margin of a book is smaller than the outside. So double check that you actually want to change this.

Interestingly passing `oneside` as an argument did nothing which was unexpected.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work! Is there another way to solve this problem? You can try it in this [link](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support)

Comment: Still works on my end.